# Properties in iOS not being set

Tags: objective-c, ios, ivar

I have the following code. self.settingsObject is always nil?  What is the issue?

```
.h file
@interface RoomConfigurationViewController : ATBaseViewController {

}
  @property (nonatomic, strong) AttendanceSettings *settingsObject;
@end


.m file
@synthesize settingsObject = _settingsObject;


NSData *settingsData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     objectForKey:kUserDefaultsSettingsObject];
self.settingsObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData];
```

Comment: Did you try NSLogging `settingsData` and then `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData]`..?

Comment: Yes, I have debugged and settingsData is there. In another part of the app, a VC, the data gets archived.

Comment: Well, you should give us more code to see what's wrong. You said `settingsData` is allocated and existing, how about NSLogging `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData]`? Also have you tried doing a formal `[settingsObject = [[AttendanceSettings alloc] init];` AND THEN `self.settingsObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:settingsData];`?

Comment: Ravi, no I have not.   Ok if I use an @interface in the .m file and do property (nonatomic, strong) Thing *settingsObject in there it fails.  But, if I move the property into the .h (interface) file it works.